# Twitter Api 1.1 not working

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, web

I will display my latest Tweets on my website. On the tweet_json.php everything is working fine but when I will display them on my website he gives me this error:

ReferenceError: listTweets is not defined

I have no idea, why. Can someone help me please?

My piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="twitter/tweet_json.php?count=3&callback=listTweets"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshID = setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON('twitter/tweet_json.php?count=3', function(data) {
                listTweets(data);
        $('.twitterfeed').trigger('create');
        });
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

I copy/paste my twitter app key correctly.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Is listTweets() defined as a javascript function somewhere?  I do not see it and that is the error you're getting.

Comment: where are you defining `listTweets`? :/

Comment: I have two files. One tweet_json.php, there is nothing defined like: listTweets() or something. In the another file tmhOAuth.php there is nothing defined like listTweets(). (https://github.com/themattharris/tmhoauth) and (https://gist.github.com/planetoftheweb/5914179).

Comment: @tilldown did you fix the error?  I'm facing the same problem..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe listTweets is defined in your

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="twitter/tweet_json.php?count=3&callback=listTweets"></script>
```

Are you sure twitter/tweet_json.php is the right path ? Look at your browser console for 404 and javascript errors.

And **I don't see any jQuery libraries** loaded before you call `$(document).ready()` 
Is that normal ?

Could we see your twitter/tweet_json.php?count=3&callback=listTweets content ?

**-EDIT-**

You just have to define your listTweets function

```
function listTweets(data) {
 // You process json results here
}
```

**-EDIT2**-

```
function listTweets(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index) {
        console.log(data[index])
  });
}
```

Watch results from your browser console. You can access fields with data[index].myfield

Comment: I have two files. One tweet_json.php, there is nothing defined like: listTweets() or something. In the another file tmhOAuth.php there is nothing defined like listTweets(). (github.com/themattharris/tmhoauth) and (gist.github.com/planetoftheweb/5914179). I have this download from this website(s). I have a jQuery libaries link on my website. My flexslider and my own writen functions are working.

Comment: It's a function you need to define. You tell the script you want it to use your function "listTweets". So define it ! Put somewhere before : function listTweets(data) { //process your results }

Comment: What do you mean with //process your results? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to loop over results depending on your json structure results. You could try my EDIT2